# How can I reference an assembly generated in Visual Studio with NAnt (and make my app work)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nant

I'm having a problem for a few hours now, and I didn't manage to find a solution by searching the web: when I create a project in Visual Studio *(C# 2010 express)* with a .dll as the target, I can use it as a reference in other VS projects without problem, but when I try to reference it in a NAnt .build file, the build process works, but my app crash, telling me it can't load the assembly or one of its dependencies.

I think maybe it's looking for the basic assemblies like `System`, `System.Windows.Forms`, etc. that I use in my .dll, but I don't know why, and how to resolve this problem.

Actually I never had to reference `System`, `System.Data`, etc. in NAnt .build files before, so I think I'm missing something...

I'm initially a graphist so very new to C#, sorry :)

Thanks,

Paul.

Comment: Can you post the NAnt code you've been trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

check that you are not trying to reference a dll built with a newer version of the .net framework from an assembly built with an older version of the .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer by myself, very simple actually: I was referencing the library on `C:\\myClass.dll` and I thought that it had to be at the same place to run the program, but it actually has to be in the same folder than the .exe file to be correctly referenced... I've got a lot of things to learn!

Actually my main problem is that at first I couldn't load the library in a 3rd party CG software (3dsmax), so I tried to use it in a "test" program and build it with NAnt and I thought it was the same issue that I had with NAnt but not at all, so it got me confused since I believed the problem was coming from VS building process while it was coming from 3dsmax.
Thank you guys for the help.